# Jqtransform Targetting specific form objects (Not all)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqtransform

I am using jqtransform:

This work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        //find all form with class jqtransform and apply the plugin
        $("form.jqtransform").jqTransform();
    });
</script>
```

But this will transform all objects inside a form with class jqtransform.

I need to transform specific objects instead so I'm trying:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        //find all form with class jqtransform and apply the plugin
        $("select.jqtransform").jqTransform();
    });
</script>
```

... to transform a select with the class of jqtransform but this is not doing anything.

Can this be done at all?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your markup looks. I'm guessing the plugin is looking for a form element, not just any element with the jqtransform class. In any case, try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    //find all form with class jqtransform and apply the plugin
    $('form.jqtransform').find('select').jqTransform();
});
```

I may have misunderstood the question. Maybe the answer you're looking for is here: http://www.code-pal.com/the-select-problem-after-using-jqtransform-and-its-solution/